# JSTL: Setting different values to a hidden attribute in a form inside a foreach on every iteration

Tags: java, html, jsp, jsf, jstl

I am iterating through a list on my JSP page using foreach. Based on this iteration, I set different values to table rows. In one column, there is a hyperlink which holds reference to a form so that onclick of this hyperlink, the form gets submitted. This form has a hidden attribute which should hold the value of a item in the list in the current iteration. Onclick, the form with this value of the list item in the hidden attribute gets submitted.

The problem is this that only the first item in the list is getting set to this hidden attribute in every iteration. The next value never gets assigned.

However, this is not the case for the other columns in the table. They have fresh values in each row/tuple.

```
   <c:forEach items="${myList}" var="item">

        <!--iterating through this list. Some code here-->
            <form action="callthis.jsp" id="request_form" method="post" target="_blank">
                    <input type="hidden" id="requestxml" name="requestxml" value="${item.requestxml}" /></form>
            <td> 
                <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('request_form').submit();"id="request">
                requestXML </a>
            </td>
       <!--some code here-->
```

Comment: Have you check that whatever values getting from ${item.requestxml} is different for every row?

Comment: In the collection over which I am iterating here, the values are different. 
But the most recent one is getting printed in all the rows in the table on my JSP page..

Comment: Please check hidden value of each row using developer tool.

Comment: The hidden value is different everywhere when I check that with developer tools. Can it be an issue with the id "requestxml"? Should I change it everytime? 
On the callthis.jsp page later, I am printing the value like this:
<%
String xmlRequest = (String)request.getParameter("requestxml"); 
request.setAttribute("xmlRequest ",xmlRequest );%>
<c:out value="${xmlRequest}">

Comment: @SanjayPatel  This is really wierd

Comment: You have to assign unique id to each form because there are multiple form with same id so it takes first one.  Refer this code .<c:forEach begin="1" end="5" var="item">

 <!--iterating through this list. Some code here-->
 <form action="callthis.jsp" id="request_form${item}" method="post" target="_blank">
  <input type="hidden" id="requestxml" name="requestxml"  value="${item}" />
 </form>
 <td><a
  href="javascript:document.getElementById('request_form${item}').submit();"
  id="request"> requestXML </a></td>
 <!--some code here-->
</c:forEach>

Comment: @SanjayPatel this solution worked. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @SanjayPatel: Answers should be in answers. And even in comment you can format the code a little by using 'back-ticks' ( \` ) around code.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

```
//1- Only one form
<form action="callthis.jsp" id="request_form" method="post" target="_blank">
    <c:forEach items="${myList}" var="item">        
        <!--iterating through this list. Some code here-->                    
        <input type="hidden" id="requestxml" name="requestxml" value="${item.requestxml}" />
        <td> 
             <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('request_form').submit();"id="request">requestXML</a>
        </td>
     </c:forEach>
</form>

//2- render multiple forms with different ID using varStatus
<c:forEach items="${myList}" var="item" varStatus="status">    
      <!--iterating through this list. Some code here-->
      <form action="callthis.jsp" id="form_${status.index}" method="post" target="_blank">
           <input type="hidden" id="requestxml" name="requestxml" value="${item.requestxml}" /></form>
           <td>
                <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('form_#{status.index}').submit();"id="request">requestXML</a>
          </td>
      </form>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to assign unique id to each form because there are multiple form with same id so it takes first one. Refer this code .This is just for example.

```
<c:forEach begin="1" end="5" var="item" varStatus="status">
    <form action="callthis.jsp" id="request_form${status.index}" method="post"
        target="_blank">
        <input type="hidden" id="requestxml" name="requestxml" value="${item}" />
    </form>
    <td><a
        href="javascript:document.getElementById('request_form${it‌​em}').submit();"
        id="request"> requestXML </a></td>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: `item` is a complex object. I'd strongly advise against using its `toString()` in a jsf id. And your post is not that well formatted.

Comment: it is just example.

Comment: But it is an example with wring suggestions. And if you make it 'correct', it is identical to the other answer... So it is kind of superfluous